# Construct a sequence of continuous function s.t. the limit is nowhere continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

1) Is there sequences of continuous function on $[0,1]$ that converge converge to a function that is nowhere continuous ?

2) Same question on all $\mathbb R$.

I was looking for a sequence that converge to $1_{\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]}$, but not conclusive.

Comment: Do you know Baire's theorem?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473573/how-discontinuous-can-the-limit-function-be), the number of discontinuous points can be dense in $[0,1]$, but the set of discontinuous points must be a meagre set by the [Baire-Osgood](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Baire-Osgood_Theorem) theorem. As a subset of a meagre or a countable union of meagre sets are also meagre (thank you [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set)), I suppose $\Bbb R$ and $[0,1]$ are not meagre, otherwise this concept would be useless. So no, it is not possible.