# Is every Baire one function define on $\mathbb{R}$ continuous a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Is every Baire one function continuous a.e.? I guess it has a positive answer. Because

1. $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Baire one function iff $f$ continuous everywhere except for meagre set.
2. A subset $A$ of $X$ is meagre that it is negligible. So, we can assume that $A$ has a measure zero (I am not sure in this part).

Therefore, $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Baire one function iff the discontinuity set of $f$ has measure zero.

Comment: Not every meagre set has measure zero, and you can't just "assume" it is.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102482/how-badly-can-dinis-theorem-fail-if-the-p-w-limit-isnt-continuous

Comment: @JonasMeyer. Thanks for the link and the answer

Comment: Note that @Jonas Meyer shows that a Baire one function on $\mathbb R$ can be **discontinuous** a.e.!

Comment: Some types of meager closed sets of positive measure are called "fat Cantor sets".